# C# thread blocks C++ program

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I created a C# lib which I use in a C++ program (don't ask me why, there are some regulations).

The lib works as expected, the C++ program can call the methods and they do what they should do.

One of those methods (in the lib) creates a new thread and this thread blocks the whole application and the C++ program won't continue.

C# lib:

```
public void StartCommunication()
        {
            if(!connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not connected!");
                return;
            }
            plattform = new RobinM2(connection);
            plattform.SendInitCommand();

            communication = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendNextCommand));
            communication.Start();
        }
```

C++:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr interf(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep));

std::wcout << interf->Test() << std::endl;

interf->ConnectToPlattform("192.168.0.1");
interf->StartCommunication();
```

The method "StartCommunication" is called, but it never returns to the main program.

My first (and ugly) idea was to call this method in a thread:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr interf(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep));

std::wcout << interf->Test() << std::endl;
interf->ConnectToPlattform("192.168.0.1");
_beginthread(test,0, (void*)&interf);

void test(void* param)
{
    RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr newparam = *(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr*) param;
    newparam->StartCommunication();
}
```

My platform doesn't support C++11 therefore I can't use "include thread".

This works, but is ugly as hell. Do you have any suggestions?

PS: Please change the title and the tags, I am not sure how to describe my problem.

Comment: It's not the Thread code.  It's likely either the call to SendInitCommand or the constructor of RobinM2 that is locking up.  Have you been able to step through with a debugger?  Add more print statements.  Visual Studios supports mixed mode debugging.  Also, how are you linking your C# code into your C++ program?

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger?  If so, step thru StartCommunication in the debugger.  If not add debug print lines (System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() to StartCommunication to see which is the last line executed before the hang.

Comment: This code is too buggy to make any guesses at it.  You created an STA thread, it must pump a message loop.  Not doing so causes deadlock.  The snippet that uses a thread is buggy, it doesn't call CoInitializeEx() so the call is always going to fail.  You don't check for errors so you'll assume it works.

Comment: @selbie thx for your fast reply. The method works, it does exactly what it should do. I can step through the lib and everything works as expected. The only problem is the C++ program. I compile the lib in "COM mode" (?) and then include the .tld file. Did I hear you right?

Comment: @DaleWilson thx for your fast reply. As I already mentioned, the method works and does what it should do. The C# program doesn't hold somewhere, the C++ just don't get executed anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant thx for your fast reply. The snipped with the thread is not complete, I also call the CoInitialize() and the other stuff, I just left it out. Yes you're right, I don't check for any errors, because it works with the thread. Did I hear you right? What else can I do?

Comment: Sigh, I hate snippets like that.  Debug the deadlock, set the Debugger Type to Mixed so you can see where the managed code is getting stuck.